# Rails joins vs. has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to rails and actually been reading just around joins querying in scope and how to use associations such as has_many and through.

It came to my attention that I don't fully understand the difference in using joins and has_many through. It seems that you can shorten a query, that instead of using joins, I can use has_many through.

Can someone give me a good explanation when and what to use between the two? Thank you!

Comment: Consider there is a user, a user can have many documents, and each documents can have many tags. By transitive property, this also means that user has (contributed to) many tags. Now suppose to show some analytics or listing, you are just interested in gathering all those tags - without `has_many through`, you will have to use `joins` explicitly to reach there.

Comment: @kiddorails thanks this summarization is quite understandable for a beginner like me :)

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are aware of [SQL joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp). `joins` method is used for the inner join of two tables, mostly in custom queries.

For example, `User.joins(:reports)` will result in the following query:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "reports" ON "reports"."user_id" = "users"."id"
```

Whereas [`has_many_through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) is the association provided Rails to establish a many-to-many relationship between two models through a third model.

For example, check out the below example from Rails [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association):

```
class Physician < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```

Comment: Primarily, I mean. The following is from Rails docs "A has_many :through association is often used to set up a many-to-many connection with another model."
Please feel free to improve the answer!

Comment: @KartikeyTanna yep I'm familiar and read with SQL joins and the rails document. I just really don't understand at first the efficiency of using has_many through since I'm used to sql joins

Comment: If you read the docs carefully, you will see the methods generated on records by setting up the associations.